# Qt - How to place a QTextEdit with left and right margins in a QVBoxLayout?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qtextedit

How to place a `QTextEdit` with left and right margins in a `QVBoxLayout`? I could use, of course, a `QHBoxLayout`, place the `QTextEdit` into that horizontal layout in between to spacings (`addSpacing(40)`) and only then the horizontal layout could add into the vertical layout, but want to know if there is a direct way of doing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the margins only for your QTextEdit and not any other element in the QVerticalLayout you can use QT stylesheets for that. You just need to give a name to the QTextEdit object (like "myMarginsTextEdit") and style it, eg:

```
QTextEdit#myMarginsTextEdit
{
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
}
```

If you are not using QT stylesheets to style your application you can still use it only to style that item. You can do it like this (imagine your QTextEdit variable is call "textEditItem"):

```
textEditItem.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {margin-left:40px; margin-right:40px}");
```

The other option is use content margins in the vertical layout but then it is applied to all elements.

Comment: Unfortunately css does not work. The reason my be the layout where the QTwxtEdit is.

Comment: Can you write down the code you are using? It is very weird that css styling cannot add the margins you need, I have use it ton of times without problems.

Comment: m_TextEdit = new QTextEdit;
    m_TextEdit->setStyleSheet("left-margin:140px;right-margin:140px");
    m_generalLayout = new QVBoxLayout;
    m_generalLayout->addLayout(m_bLayout);
    m_generalLayout->addStretch();
    m_generalLayout->addWidget(m_qLabel);
    m_generalLayout->addWidget(m_TextEdit);
    m_generalLayout->addWidget(m_aLabel);
    m_generalLayout->addWidget(m_aLieEdit);
    m_generalLayout->addStretch();
    m_generalLayout->addLayout(m_buttonLayout);
    m_generalLayout->addSpacing(15);

    setLayout(m_generalLayout);

Comment: BYW I get:
Unknown property left-margin
Unknown property right-margin

Comment: Need to be written setStyleSheet("margin-left:40px;margin-right:40px"); Please correct your answer in order to make possible for me to choose you answer as the correct.

Comment: Ups it is true, margin word is first, sorry my mistake, correcting it... XD. Has it work properly then?

Answer (score 7):

There is

```
void QLayout::setContentsMargins ( int left, int top, int right, int bottom );
```

but this sets a margin around the whole thing. If you want margins on just the `QTextEdit` and nothing else in the layout then you have to use the `QHBoxLayout`  approach you mentioned. I'm not aware of any other tricks to get around that.

Comment: This was usefull too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you are using Qt Designer or doing this by hand in code.

In code:
The QLayout class has a setContentsMargins property that you can use to set the left and right to whatever you want.  There are even two flavors, one that takes left, top, right, bottom as separate arguments and one that takes a QMargins object.

Qt Designer:
Just set the margins properties directly.